# Prove the inequality $ \sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \geq \frac{|a-b|}{\sqrt{2}}$

Tags: inequality

Please help me to prove the inequality
$$
\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \geq \frac{|a-b|}{\sqrt{2}}.
$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Square both sides and multiply by $2$, and you'll find that this is equivalent to proving that

$$2(a^2 + b^2) \ge |a - b|^2 = (a - b)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that $(a-b)^2+(a+b)^2=2(a^2+b^2)$.